# What is the significance of /etc/protocols in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, protocols

What is the use case and usage of `/etc/protocols`?

I can see it lists the number of protocols available. But what is the significance?

For example, my Linux machine is not running OSPF but I see OSPF in `/etc/protocols`.

What does it mean? What is the significance of that file? Do we edit that file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file is documented in [`man 5 protocols`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/protocols.5.html):

> This file is a plain ASCII file, describing the various DARPA
> internet protocols that are available from the TCP/IP subsystem.
> It should be consulted instead of using the numbers in the ARPA
> include files, or, even worse, just guessing them.  These numbers
> will occur in the protocol field of any IP header.

It’s a list of protocols, not tied to protocols actually supported on your system. It’s the local equivalent of [the IANA’s list of protocol numbers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers). It can be interrogated using [the `getprotobyname` and `getprotobynumber`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getprotoent.3.html) functions.

It is typically used to provide a name for a protocol seen in use, or to determine the protocol number for a user-specified protocol name; see for example [this use in the Unbound DNS resolver](https://sources.debian.org/src/unbound/1.13.1-1/sldns/wire2str.c/?hl=1489#L1489).

It shouldn’t be modified:

> Keep this file untouched since changes would result in incorrect
> IP packages.  Protocol numbers and names are specified by the
> IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority).

You would only need to change it if you were implementing a new protocol over IP — not a new protocol over TCP/UDP (which are listed in `/etc/services`): something like SCTP, not HTTP. If you were doing that then you might want to modify `/etc/protocols` temporarily; but before publication you’d request a new assignment from the IANA (which is quite straightforward), and then your protocol would be added to the IANA’s list and would eventually make its way into `/etc/protocols` updates.

Comment: Thank you for such a long elaboration! Cheers Stephen